# Laravel - optionally include api resource relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have medications and batches and I want to optionally load the batches relation depending on where I call the relation from.

I do have something that seems to work, but I am not sure it is the intended way.

My medication resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class MedicationResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'batches' => $this->when(in_array('batches', $this->additional), $this->batches),
        ];
    }
}
```

Then I call the resource from my controller:

```
$resource = new MedicationResource($medication);

$resource->additional(['batches']);

return $resource;
```

Is this the best way to achieve optional relationship loading?

Thanks

Comment: you can try by overriding constructor. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23826#issuecomment-385627817